# get_terms return errors

Tags: customization, taxonomy, terms, errors

Hi when i try to `get_terms();` in theme options via this code

```
$catalogs_terms = get_terms( 'catalogs' );
   $mycatalogs = array( -1 => 'Select a catalog' );
   if ( $catalogs_terms ) {
      foreach ( $catalogs_terms as $catalog_term ) {
         $mycatalogs[$catalog_term->term_id] = $catalog_term->name;
      }
   }
```

return empty but this code is working fine every where in pages etc.
when i try to `print_r( $catalogs_terms )` output i am getting errors

```
Array ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid Taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

i don't understand where am i wrong?
my function for register taxonomy

```
    add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies', 0 );

function my_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Catalogs', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Catalog', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Catalogs', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Catalogs', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Catalog:', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Catalog Name', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Catalogs', 'mytextdomain' ),
    );  

    // register catalogs hierarchical (like categories)
    register_taxonomy( 'catalogs',
        array( 'news' ),
        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'catalogs' )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: At a guess you're calling that code before the taxonomy is registered, which is why you get an error object back.. Where specifically are you calling `get_terms`? (inside a function? Yes, which hook is it attached to?)

Comment: in my function.php i have registerd my post type and then taxonomy and below is this code for get terms without function and hook with this code i am able to get categories fine

Comment: Can you put a copy of your functions file into a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [pastie](http://www.pastie.org/) so i can see how it looks in the file? (i can't see the issue offhand, so there must be something missing from what's posted).

Comment: @t31os checkout my code here http://www.pastie.org/1734827

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i was mentioning before, it's a case of your term fetching occuring before the taxonomy has been registered.

The init action occurs after the theme's functions file has been included, so if you're looking for terms directly in the functions file, you're doing so before they've actually been registered.

Here's a portion of the code from `wp-settings.php` that includes the theme functions and does the `init` action.

```
// Load the functions for the active theme, for both parent and child theme if applicable.
if ( TEMPLATEPATH !== STYLESHEETPATH && file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
    include( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' );
if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
    include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' );

do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );

// Load any template functions the theme supports.
require_if_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails', ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post-thumbnail-template.php' );

register_shutdown_function( 'shutdown_action_hook' );

// Set up current user.
$wp->init();

/**
 * Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated. WP continues
 * to load on the init hook that follows (e.g. widgets), and many plugins instantiate
 * themselves on it for all sorts of reasons (e.g. they need a user, a taxonomy, etc.).
 *
 * If you wish to plug an action once WP is loaded, use the wp_loaded hook below.
 */
do_action( 'init' );
```

As you can see the `init` action doesn't fire until after the theme functions file is included, therefore any term retrieval must occur after init. I can't really advise you any further though because you've only shown me a portion of your code, so i've not much of an idea of the context you're trying to use the term function in, but it certainly can't be called directly in the functions file(outside a callback hooked onto a specific action/filter because the code will run to soon).

Hopefully the above illustrates the problem enough for you.. :)

**Additional note:**
This function is missing a var from the global statement(you'd see PHP notices if you had debug turned on).

```
function news_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    global $post;
```

That should read..

```
function news_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    global $post, $post_ID;
```

.. because code inside that function references that var, but the variable doesn't have scope inside the function, my above suggested change will fix that.

### Follow-up #1

When creating a plugin or theme page, you first have to setup/register that page, this is typically done like so..

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_theme_menu');

function my_theme_menu() {
    add_theme_page( 'Theme Settings', 'Theme Settings', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_theme_settings' );
}
function my_theme_settings() {
    
    // Code to display/handle theme options would be here
    // You get_terms() call should work inside this function just fine

}
```

If the theme page is created differently, *specific to the premium theme you're using* then i can't really help as they tend to use a framework that is entirely different to regular WordPress themes.

Comment: @t31os is there a way to get terms from wpdb? or some other

Comment: Why? Is there a specific reason you **must** fetch them directly in the functions file? I can't think why you'd need to.

Comment: i want to display terms in theme admen options panel for select a term to show news within selected term on a page with get_option

Comment: Ok but your theme options page is a registered page right? (ie. you added it via one of the `add_%type%_page` functions inside a function hooked onto `admin_menu`) That registered page has a callback function, if you do the term fetching inside that function it should be fine.

Comment: i can,t understand how to do this please any advice Thanks

Comment: Ok, well post up the code you use for creating the theme options page and i'll have a look.. :)

Comment: here any place to paste my code to only show you can i email you my code

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, why not use just pastie/pastebin?

Comment: i am using this code in my premium theme

Comment: Example has been added to the answer..

Comment: yes my theme page is looks like as your's but i have added it to menu  `add_menu_page`

Comment: I'm not sure it matters specifically which `add_TYPE_page`(where TYPE is applicable page type) function you used, if you call get_terms inside the function it should work just fine. It works here for me... so if it's not working for you, then you'll have to narrow down the cause, i can't help you fix a problem without knowing the cause(or at least having some clues about how to recreate the problem described).

Comment: Thanks very much now it's working fine as i wish Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to mess around with Wordpress nonsense of it ignoring taxonomies which clearly exist in the database, whether they be registered or not, you can just use a replacement function like this to grab the taxonomy at any time.

```
function custom_get_terms($taxonomy) {
 global $wpdb;

 $out = array();

 $a = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT t.name,t.slug,t.term_group,x.term_taxonomy_id,x.term_id,x.taxonomy,x.description,x.parent,x.count FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy x LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON (t.term_id = x.term_id) WHERE x.taxonomy=%s;",$taxonomy));

 foreach ($a as $b) {
  $obj = new stdClass();
  $obj->term_id = $b->term_id;
  $obj->name = $b->name;
  $obj->slug = $b->slug;
  $obj->term_group = $b->term_group;
  $obj->term_taxonomy_id = $b->term_taxonomy_id;
  $obj->taxonomy = $b->taxonomy;
  $obj->description = $b->description;
  $obj->parent = $b->parent;
  $obj->count = $b->count;
  $out[] = $obj;
 }

 return $out;
}
```