# Register Taxonomy earlier so it can be used in functions.php and admin-ajax.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy, ajax, register-taxonomy

This is a follow up to [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/get-terms-return-errors/13482#13482), outlining why I can not use the get_terms function while in functions.php (actually calling via ajax/admin_ajax.php).

I can grab the terms (custom tax) on any post, on any page, except when in my ajax function. I receive the dreaded 'taxonomy does not exist' error when dumping the value of get_terms.

The problem is, the taxonomy is registered *after* I call the function to find the terms.

The question is, how do I register the tax early enough so I can use this function? My code to register the custom post type and taxonomy is first in my functions.php (included via an external php to keep functions.php clean)

```
/************************************************ 
*
* 1.0 ------------------ Events ----------------
*
************************************************/


// 1. Custom Post Type Registration (Events)
add_action( 'init', 'create_event_postype', 0 );

function create_event_postype() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Events', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'events'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
    'new_item' => __('New Event'),
    'view_item' => __('View Event'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Events'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No events found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No events found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
);

$args = array(
    'label' => __('Events'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', // ?
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/icons/events.png',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "events" ),
    'supports'=> array('title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'editor', 'custom-fields') ,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'tf_eventtype')
);

register_post_type( 'tf_events', $args);

}

// 2. Custom Taxonomy Registration (Event Types)
add_action( 'init', 'create_eventtype_taxonomy', 0 );
function create_eventtype_taxonomy() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Event Type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Event Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Event Types' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Event Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Event Types' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event Type' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Event Type' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event Type' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Event Type Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate event types with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove event types' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used event types' ),
);

register_taxonomy('tf_eventtype','tf_events', array(
    'label' => __('Event Type'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event-type' ),
));
}
```

Here is some pseudo code to show how I'm calling this function

from a custom page, I call a function via AJAX (ajax-admin.php)

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "<? bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", //Built in WP AJAX
            data: data, 
            success:  function(data){
                         //console.log('search complete');
                         $("#event-list").html(data)                                                         
                         }  
    });
```

Here is the function that calls a custom query, and where get_terms fails.

```
/****************************************************************
*
* 1.0 Calendar AJAX Queries
*
****************************************************************/
// if both logged in and not logged in users can send this AJAX request,
// add both of these actions, otherwise add only the appropriate one
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_calendar_search', 'calendar_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_calendar_search', 'calendar_search' );

function calendar_search() {        
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tf_events',         
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        // - loop start -
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

         while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); /*Shows the posts that are available. */

                //Event Type
                $cats = get_the_terms($post->ID , 'tf_eventtype'); //the function that fails. All other custom data works fine 

                echo 
                '<article class="post" id="post-'. $post->ID . '"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">                       
                   <time></time>
                   <h2  itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() . '</a></h2>                
                   <div class="entry">
                     <p itemprop="location">';
                       if($cats) foreach($cats as $cat){ 
                            echo " | " . $cat->name;
                       }
                       echo 
                     "</p>  
                   </div><!--#entry-->
                 </article>";

            endwhile; 
         } else {
            echo "<h2 class='month'>Sorry, no events found!</h2>";            
          } 
        die(); // this is required to return a proper result
```

}

Comment: Show us where you are attempting to use `get_terms`. `init` action should run before any properly hooked ajax requests.

Comment: +1 for @Milo. init action *is* triggered before `wp_ajax_*` actions. After that, using `functions.php` earlier hook available is `after_setup_theme`.

Comment: I have a custom calendar page and an ajax call queries the database (wp_query). I use get_terms inside the custom query, inside my ajax-functions include. How can I show you this code?

page-calendar.php > ajax call through admin-ajax.php > custom wp_query > get_terms inside the loop

Comment: Just added the ajax call and the functions that get called.

Yes, I include the files, only to keep my functions.php cleaner.

Comment: What is odd, is I can manually call get_terms (passing a post ID) anywhere else on my page - it only fails when inside my calendar_search() function

Comment: that's not odd, an ajax request is a separate http request. when you're in the template the init action most certainly executed long ago, but it's an entirely different context than your ajax request. it sounds like you're calling calendar_search elsewhere beside the ajax hooks. your problem is not in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

So, thanks to G. M.'s help I was able to debug the problem more efficiently, now that I knew init was indeed not being called. I started stripping out all extraneous functions from my functions.php file and I realized I called do_action twice, as I have many functions run through admin-ajax.php. The do_action calls must only be used once! Odd how the bug presented itself!

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : null;

//These functions take an ajax call and then call the appropriate PHP function
// this hook is fired if the current viewer is not logged in
do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $action );
do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $action );
```

Comment: how do you have things set up where you have to manually call `do_action` to fire ajax callbacks? you're doing something strange.

Comment: Strange isn't good, so please let me know if you have a better suggestion. Basically, the do_action routes the ajax call to the different php functions in functions.php (using add_action). Tutorial was from [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/), under "Best Practices"

Comment: I don't think they're telling you to add that code, that's the code that's in `admin-ajax.php` that fires your ajax callback, [see it in source here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L70).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `global $post;` before use `$post` variable:

```
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
  global $post;
  $cats = get_the_terms($post->ID , 'tf_eventtype');
  //... and so on
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy! Still getting the same error.



object(WP_Error)#188 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Your code work for me (after adding global $post;), I've tested. Are you sure that the file with code that register taxonomy is included? Try to add a `die` on first line, what happen? @Nate

Comment: die() on the first line of calendar_search()? I will try right now.

Yes, there might be another culprit involved. I have used this same code on another site and have never seen the particular error.

Comment: Yes, die() kills the script both on calendar_search() and before I register my taxonomy.

Again, get_terms works everywhere on the page/site except in this one function.

Comment: Try to put `if ( did_action('init') ) die('inited');` as 1st line of `calendar_search()` function. It will prove `init` is performed and problem is elsewhere, even if I can't see where...

Comment: Init was NOT performed. Script did not die when I added those lines.

So this proves the taxonomy does NOT exist when that function is running...which brings me back to my original question - how do I 'init sooner'?

(And thank you for your persistence in helping me with this problem. It's an odd one!)

Comment: @Nate `admin-ajax.php` include `wp-load.php` on line `20` that include `wp-config.php` that include `wp-settings.php` that contain `do_action('init');`. `wp_ajax_*` action are performed on line `71` so when `wp_ajax_*` are fired `'init'` **must** be performed. Something is wrong on your code, but not what you have posted...

Answer (score 0):

The "invalid taxonomy" message occurs because when the ajax call is made, not all the taxonomies have been registered because all the plugins have not been initialized.

the solution is to launch the hook ajax after the initialization and so it works ok

ex.

```
        add_action( 'init', function() {

            //add the ajax hook only when all the taxonomies have been registered
            add_action('wp_ajax_my_action',  function() {

                $result = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy_name' );
            }

        }, 99);
```